# How to clear (set ZERO) all the memory regions (Stack, heap, etc.) of a process when killing it (Linux/Android - kernel)?

Tags: android, c, linux, security, memory

In Linux/Android, when a process is killed OS kernel de-allocates all the memory (like stack, heap, etc.) associated with a process & puts it back to the memory pool; but IT IS NOT CLEARED in the RAM (i.e. these values would still be visible when a RAM dump is taken ??).

Please can you let me know how to clear (set ZERO) all the memory associated with a process to be killed?

I know "mm_struct" structure (in "sched.h") holds all the memory related info of a process. Do I need to manually go & reset all the params of this struct to ensure that the process' memory is cleared? If so, please guide me where I should be calling this clearing function.

OR

Is there another simpler way to clearing all the memory? Please let me know....

---

[update from comment:]

I am trying to ensure no one can steal the data from the pages (or dump) after the process is killed. I am fine with user space or kernel space solution.

Comment: First question: why do you want to do this?

Comment: Also, note that `mm_struct` is a kernel-space data structure.  Are you talking about a kernel-space or a user-space solution?

Comment: Also, note that due to the virtual memory system, there is no clear definition of "the RAM" associated with your process; pages may be arbitrarily handed off to other processes at any point during the lifetime of your process.

Comment: @Oli:
@ Oli: Thanks for replying. I am trying to ensure no one can steal the data from the pages (or dump) after the process is killed. 

I am fine with user space or kernel space solution.

Comment: For security concerns, ALL memory requested by a process is zeroed before it's assigned.  Essentially, it's mapped to a zero-filled page, with COW (copy-on-write) properties, so the first write causes a (real) page to be allocated and zeroed, then written to.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6004816/kernel-zeroes-memory for a better (longer) answer.

Comment: @ lornix: Thanks a lot. The concern is: if a RAM dump is taken right after the process kill memory would still contain stale data from that process & this data is considered as 'leaked to the outside world'? 

I am trying to address this.

I am trying to modify the do_exit() in 'exit.c' (kernel) to go through all the vma_pages (start to end) and mark them as ZEROes (snippet shown below) .. Am I doing the right thing or is there a good solution?

void do_exit(long code) 
{
 ...
 for_each_vma_region
 do memset(0);
 exit_mm(tsk);
...
}

Comment: If a process terminates abnormally `exit()` won't necessarily get called.

Comment: Related: http://security.stackexchange.com/q/42179

Comment: Do you really need to clear *all* memory, or would something like `sodium_mlock` and `sodium_memzero` on just the important bits (via the libsodium library) suffice, along with the usual no-coredumps and appropriate signal handling to limit shenanigans?