# Uninitialized local variable used? yet initialized? whats the problem

Tags: c++

Why do i keep getting uninitialized local vairables in the second function even though i already did initialized them?

> Error C4700   uninitialized local variable 'x1'
>   Error C4700   uninitialized local variable 'x2'

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
bool is_prime(int n, bool is_prime = 0)
{
    for (int i = 2; i < n; i++)
    {
        bool is_prime = true;
        if (n % i == 0)
            is_prime = false;
    }
    return is_prime;
}

int sumPrime(int , int )
{
    int x1, x2; // keeps saying its unitialized

    int sum = 0;
    for ( x1; x1 < x2; x1++)
    {
        if (is_prime(x1))
        {
            sum += x1;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    int n1, n2;
    cout << " enter two ns" << endl;
    cin >> n1 >> n2;
    cout << sumPrime(n1, n2) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How are `int x1, x2; ` initialised?

Comment: as integers? i dont get the question sorry!

Comment: `bool is_prime = true;` is a whole new `is_prime` and hides the argument.

Comment: @Sarah_Xx looks like you might benefit from the good C++ book: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list?s=1|994.2496

Comment: It looks like you might be thinking that `int x1, x2;` are initialized to the arguments of `sumPrime` but in fact `sumPrime` has two unnamed and unused parameters which are set to the arguments' values, and `x1` and `x2` are left uninitialized.

Comment: `int sumPrime(int , int )` on a function definition means roughly "you need to pass me two `int`s but I dont care what their values are (and i have no way to access them)"

Comment: Your second function has unnamed arguments - did you mean to accept x1 and x2 in the argument list (and therefore initialize them)?

Comment: I highly recommend using different names between variables and functions.  In your `is_prime()` function, you declare a `is_prime` variable in the `for` loop.

Comment: BTW, you should move your declaration of `bool is_prime = true` before the `for` loop in the `is_prime()` function.  Otherwise, the `is_prime` variable is local to inside the loop and will be destroyed after each iteration in the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are various problems inside your code:

The `is_prime()` function should be like:

```
bool is_prime(int n) // <-- No use of 'is_prime' parameter here...
{
    bool is_prime = true; // should be outside the loop...
    for (int i = 2; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (n % i == 0)
            is_prime = false;
    }
    return is_prime;
}
```

and the `sumPrime()` function:

```
int sumPrime(int x1, int x2)
{
    /*int x1, y1; Just forget these variables, they are not even initialized*/
    int sum = 0;
    for ( /*x1 <- It is not syntatically correct, it is not an expression, so just leave it blank*/; x1 < x2; x1++)
    {
        if (is_prime(x1))
        {
            sum += x1;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

---

**Explanation:**

The `is_prime()` function..., what you have done here is that you have declared the variable `is_prime` (***Not the function, look closely***) both in the parameters and also inside the loop...

This, in fact, will not cause a problem, but will *shadow* your previous declaration...

Also, there is no need for `is_prime` to **be present in the parameters** because it is **mostly useless** (*Maybe because I don't know what you are trying to achieve*)... But you have to choose one, **so there is something like this you *can* do:**

```
bool is_prime(int n, bool& is_prime) // Make is_prime a reference and assign to it...
```

**Also, change this line:**

```
bool is_prime = true;
```

**to:**

```
is_prime = true; // Remove bool specifier, don't declare 'is_prime' again!
```

---

As for your other function, it is, in fact, not even an old syntax, and don't even ask about C++, the only way you can [*declare functions*](https://www.studytonight.com/cpp/functions-in-cpp) in C++ is:

```
<return_type> <function-name>(<parameters>) { <body> }
```

<sub>Note that this is pseudo-syntax of a function declaration and is followed by most languages nowadays...</sub>

So **your function should also look like:**

```
bool is_prime(int x1, int x2) { /* <body> */ }
```

And also remove the declarations of *x1* and *x2* **inside the function** to prevent [***variable shadowing***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) (Just like the above example)...

---

> **Edit:** Also, Looking at these *small mistakes*, anyone will tell you to look at a good [C++ book](https://www.hackerearth.com/blog/algorithms/list-top-c-c-books-programming-enthusiasts/)...

Comment: i am confused? isnt initialized meaning declaring them as a variable? so if i wrote int x1, x2; i would then initialized them then right?

Comment: No, declaring them doesn't mean they are initialized, when you declare them, they are not assigned any values, and since these variables are not **classes**, they are not having any default values either and your program runs on [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), see [what happens when you don't initialize a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30172416/uninitialized-variable-behaviour-in-c)...

Comment: yeah but wont they be assigned to the value once i call the function? thats why i didnt declare it only intiaizlied it

Comment: I don't see any attempts of an assignment in your code and I don't fully get what you mean either...

Comment: i mean i didnt give x in sumprime any value because in main i will give it a value

Comment: No no, see, you have declared those variables **inside the `sumPrime()` function** and hence it is a *local variable* and *local variables* **can't** be accessed using any other function outside the *function where they are defined*...

Comment: what about bool_prime? i mean whats the difference then?

Answer (score 4):

Your curious parameter syntax

```
int sumPrime(int , int )
{
    int x1, x2;
```

dates from pre-standardised C (although I don’t know of an old compiler that would have compiled this particular variant) and it never made it into C++.

You need

```
int sumPrime(int x1, int x2)
```

Comment: Nice, I would not have thought of that. But, was it not `int sumPrime(int,int) int x1, x2 { ... }` or something like that?

Comment: Even in good ole c it would be incorrect, naming parameters would have to be done before opening brackets, like `int baz (x, y) int x, y {...}`

Comment: This is it. It rings bells now. There were usually a semi-colon before the opening bracket.

Comment: The old syntax was `int baz() int x, y { ... }`

Comment: Since it wasn't standardized, I guess each compiler family had its own syntax. But the K&R book was an informal spec at the time, right? So clearly, [`baz(x,y) int x, int y; { /* ... */ }`](https://archive.org/details/TheCProgrammingLanguageFirstEdition/page/n29)

Comment: The one I remember had the declarations before the opening brace - so the way the OP has it is a variant. But to me it looks like they are attempting to follow the old way, albeit in error: perhaps in an attempt to get something to compile on a C++ compiler.