# Using garbage value(not initialized value) as id

Tags: c++

Before ask I'm not the native speaker pardon for my poor english

Reading some book about c++ and the book mentioned variables should be initialize after declared. Otherwise variable having a garbage value and this may cause some problem. This garbage values are random and not predictable, what if using this garbage value as a ID?
I tried to find relational topic an google and couldn't find any result

Please leave a comment of idea of references

Comment: What's in an not initialized variable, is not defined: it may be garbage or zero or anything else, depending on the compiler and its setting. You certainly cannot rely on it's being unique or unpredictable or use it as a source of randomness.

Comment: Not initialized variable I mentioned was variable that just declared. e.g (int a;)
Thanks for the comment :)

Answer (score 2):

When you **initialize** a non-static(local) variable and use/read/print it **before** assigning a variable to it, the action is `undefined behavior`.

When you encounter `undefined behavior`:

- You **cannot** assume that there's any value in that memory space to begin with
- You **cannot** assume that the value won't change throughout the code execution, therefore, it's **not** ideal to use it as an ID
- You **cannot** even assume that the program will **run**, or it will crash/freeze/etc... as everything action from that point on is `undefined`

Theoretically, an `undefined behavior` permits anything to happen (obviously in reality there's many restrictions to try and keep it from doing everything and probably sending everyone your pictures, corrupt all your files and frying your computer afterward).

For example, with this piece of code:

```
int num;
int a = num;
int b = num;
```

When you print it out, `a` and `b` is **not** guaranteed to have identical value, or the program will run at all. It's different with each systems/compilers.

As such, one **must never** rely on an `undefined behavior` to act normally.

Quote from @AnT:

> So in general, the popular answer that "it is initialized with
> whatever garbage was in memory" is not even remotely correct.
> *Uninitialized* variable's behavior is different from that of a variable
> *initialized with garbage*.

However, never mistakes `undefined` for `inconsistency/randomness`. For a (pretty bad) real life example, a broken pipe may be unexpected behavior, but the stream of water that hits you isn't inconsistent or random (until the pipe is fixed, of course).

An example when undefined behavior isn't simply taking some garbage value and results in some bizarre stuff: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140627-00/?p=633

Related :

- [Uninitialized variable behaviour in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30172416/uninitialized-variable-behaviour-in-c)
- [What happens to a declared, uninitialized variable in C? Does it have a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597405/what-happens-to-a-declared-uninitialized-variable-in-c-does-it-have-a-value)

Answer (score 1):

Nothing guarantees that an uninitialized variable contains garbage. It *may* be garbage, but in fact, any access to such variable yields [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub), which means that literally anything may happen. It may be garbage, it may be constant, it may crash, it may contain previously used data, it may work like expected, but only with some compilers, etc. One is not supposed to rely on anything that comes from such variable and build any logic based on that. And, certainly, it cannot be a source of uniqueness or randomness.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should not use garbage value as ID.

Since not detail about your question, I am Considering your id is an unique value also by using your ID you are going to retrieve some value.
if that is the case then,

you cannot because on each and every run your garbage value may change.

And Garbage value in the sense it may be a numerical alphanumerical even not a proper value may come.