# why undefined operator when applied to uninitialized variable

Tags: c++

in bjarne stroustroups Programming Principles and Practice using C++ he writes on page 78-79:

```
double x;  //we "forgot" to initialize

double z = 2.0+x; //meaning of + and the value of z are undefined
```

why is here the meaning of + undefined? I get that x's value is undefined, but it is given a distinct type. with the type the + operator should be well defined.

Comment: The result of the addition is undefined (since one of the operands is not initialized).

Comment: The value of `x` is *indeterminate*. In C++ using indeterminate values in any way leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: *"Undefined behavior means **anything can happen including but not limited to the program giving your expected output. But never rely on the output of a program that has UB. The program may just crash.**"* See dupe [Undefined, unspecified and implementation-defined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior)

Comment: Also see [(Why) is using an uninitialized variable undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11962457/why-is-using-an-uninitialized-variable-undefined-behavior) and [Uninitialized variable behaviour in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30172416/uninitialized-variable-behaviour-in-c)

Comment: "Undefined behavior" refers to the **entire program**, not to some part of it. The behavior of **the program** is undefined; the language definition does not tell you what the program does.

Answer (score 0):

Undefined behavior means undefined behavior.

It would be possible that the random garbage that ends up inhabiting the same bits as that `double` turns out to be an invalid representation of a floating point value, and the CPU would generate an exception on any mathematical operation on an invalid `double` value.

It would be more accurate to say that this behavior is not prohibited by the C++ standard.

Note that this applies only if `double` is declared in automatic scope. statically-scoped objects are zero-initialized by default.