# How to fix "Variable declaration in condition must have an initializer"

Tags: c++, c++11

I am writing a program that counts the number of vowels that the user inputs but it is giving me the error "Variable declaration in condition must have an initializer". How do you fix it?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int isVowel(char c) 
{
  char Vowels[] = {'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U', 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'};
  if (c in Vowels)
    return true;
}

int main()
{
  int n;
  int numVowel = 0;
  char c;

  cin >> n;

  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
  {
    cin >> c;
    if (isVowel(c))
      numVowel++;
  }

  cout << "Number of vowels = " << numVowel << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is no `in` operator in C++.

Comment: Is there an alternative for it like in python?

Comment: C++ is not English. You have to follow the rules of C++.

Comment: nope, you will have to do something like this: for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) if( Vowels[i]==c ) ... or use a higher level type: std::vector or std::set

Comment: @AxelPodehl Well you could use `memchr` or `find`. You don't have to write an explicit loop.

Comment: Besides that, what does the `isVowel` function return if the condition is false?

Comment: I would find strchr() less intimidating to start with, so how about: if( strchr(Vowels,c) ) return true; else return false; and the return type should be bool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `in` operator in C++.

You probably want this:

```
int isVowel(char c)
{
  static const char Vowels[] = { 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U', 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' };
  for (const auto & v : Vowels)
    if (c == v)
      return true;

  return false;
}
```

Bonus: you should make `Vowels` static and const, it might be a bit more performant.

Comment: What does "auto & v : Vowels" mean?

Comment: Time to open your C text book: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for

Comment: Same as `for x in Vowels` in Python, near enough (except & is a ref so will let you change things even chars, unless you use `const`)

Comment: You can save some space if you only store lowercase vowels and use `to_lower` when performing the comparison. Moreover, you can pass `c` as `const`.

Comment: @DavideSpataro for const: already edited, but calling `to_lower` take probably more than the 5 bytes you save storing only lowercase vowels.

Comment: In my opinion, which might be wrong, I think the code as above is good enough. I think optimization should be done using a profiler when the need arises. You don't want to piss off the legendary Donald Knuth by prematurely optimizing :)

Answer (score 8):

Use `std::find`

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>

bool isVowel(char c)
{
    static constexpr std::array<char, 10> Vowels{ 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U', 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' };
    return std::find(Vowels.begin(), Vowels.end(), c) != Vowels.end();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Others have answered adequately to this question, but the following could be a valid alternative:

```
bool isVowel(const char c) {
  switch (tolower(c)){
      case 'a':
      case 'e':
      case 'i':
      case 'o':
      case 'u':
          return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

---

I ran some benchmarks and comparing all solution proposed on a random string of size 10k ; [Here are the results](http://quick-bench.com/LWn2H-3bPkoFB0Dp4n9XnhdOkHg) (the lower the bar the better=faster the code):

1. `Clang 7.0 -O3 -std=c++20`

[image]

2. `gcc-8.1 -O3 -std+c++20`
   [image]

Comment: Using default in the switch to return false; rather than returning false at the end?

Comment: Might also work. I personally find this way more clear (and shorter)

Comment: Yes, it does work, but the reason I prefer putting a default is that you signal that the function will end in the switch. It blocks other people from putting logic between the switch and the return false. But it's only my personal take. I think your way works well too. I'm just being really picky here.

Comment: @TuanDT yeah, it make sense.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest is this one:

```
bool isVowel(char c) 
{
  char Vowels[] = "AEIOUaeiou";
  if ( strchr(Vowels,c) )
    return true;
  else
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Easy, but that's a pure "C" solution.

Comment: Oh and your `Vowels` array is not NUL terminated... `strchr`won't end well

Comment: True, but easy beats complicated (see KISS principle :-)

Comment: @Jabberwocky, I think  char Vowels[] = { 'A','E' } is another way of saying char Vowels[] = "AE" - is it inot ?

Comment: Nope, but `char Vowels[] = { 'A','E', 0}` is

Comment: @Jabberwocky, thanks for bringing this up. Here's more on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37955281/are-list-initialized-char-arrays-still-null-terminated

Answer (score 0):

To this, you can also replace if in with for-loop in following way

```
for(int i=0 ; i < Vowels.length-1 ; i++) {
     if(Vowels[i]==c)
     return true; 
}
```