# Will the above array a1 have null character in the 2nd index even though i haven not placed it

Tags: c++

```
char a1[30]={'h','e'}
```

will the above array a1 have null character in the 2nd index even though i haven not placed it.

```
char a2[30]={'h','e','\0'}
```

when printing,a1 and a2 show same output, hence I think a1 will have null character in the 2nd index.But i am not sure.

Comment: There is a more detailed answer to your question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37955281/are-list-initialized-char-arrays-still-null-terminated

Comment: This could probably marked as duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler has initialized the rest of the 28 bytes of a1 with 0.
Hence both a1 and a2 have same output.

Comment: with 0 or with \0 since it is character array?

Comment: some compilers initializes the rest of the values to 0 and some not.

Comment: @spandanBanerjee `\0` is just `0` in octal format. They are the same numeric value.  So yes, assigning a numeric 0 to a `char` makes it a null character.

Comment: @gocjack if an array has a fixed size, and is not explicitly initialized with that many values, then the rest of the of values MUST be initialized to 0.  The standard dictates that. If a compiler is not doing that, then it is not conforming to the standard

Answer (score 3):

Syntax error will be there. If you fix it, yes, `h[2]` and further elements will be initialized with zeroes.

[Array initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array_initialization) **Initialization from brace-enclosed lists**

> When an array is initialized with a brace-enclosed list of initializers, the first initializer in the list initializes the array element at index zero (unless a designator is specified) (since C99), and each subsequent initializer without a designator (since C99)initializes the array element at index one greater than the one initialized by the previous initializer.

```
int x[] = {1,2,3}; // x has type int[3] and holds 1,2,3
int y[5] = {1,2,3}; // y has type int[5] and holds 1,2,3,0,0
int z[3] = {0}; // z has type int[3] and holds all zeroes
```

Comment: Right. `\0` is zero: `'\0' == 0` is true.