# Uninitialized pointer, points to zero

Tags: c++, pointers, initialization

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    int* pt;
    std::cout << pt << std::endl;
    if(pt)
        std::cout << "true" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "false" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This code fragment evaulate to false. What is more it prints 0 in

```
    std::cout << pt << std::endl;
```

I thought that uninitialized pointers points to some random address, which may contain garbage value. In this case it points to 0 value like i would assign it to nullptr. Could someone clarify this for me?

Comment: it is possible that the random address could have been null_ptr. That meaning, the memory left over at the location that the pointer was declared could have originally been 0.

Comment: Who said `0` is not garbage?

Comment: It is so, ackward for me because now it always shows 0 and about one week before the pointer was really pointing to some random address. That is why i am interested why it like that.

Answer (score 1):

This code invokes *Undefined Behavior* (UB), since the pointer is used uninitialized.

The compiler should emit a warning, when a warning flag is used, like `-Wall` for example:

```
warning: 'pt' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
     std::cout << pt << std::endl;
                  ^~
```

It just happens, that at this run, on your system, it had the behavior of a null pointer. That means that the garbage value the pointer takes, happens to be 0. However, notice that, [kernel zeroes appear relatively often](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6004816/kernel-zeroes-memory).

Comment: It is also interesting to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6004816/kernel-zeroes-memory) which explains why you often still get 0.

Comment: Agree @Pi, injected that into the question. Hope you like it now.

Comment: Actually, an answer with that link would have been more useful on the dupe target than it is here.

Comment: @gsamaras Never disliked it ;)

Comment: I attempted to answer there too @BaummitAugen, but I need to catch the bus now! Pi that's good, thanks!